# Discord adding a comma to message string

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a command which writes the text I send minus the /sendchat part to a text file, when i do /sendchat message it adds a extra comma so its output is ", message" This comma actually messes up the thing im trying to trigger with the output.

I have tried doing another split for it with the comma, I have tried putting the comma in the main split so "prefix + "sendchat ," " and that seems to just include the whole command anyways with /sendchat on it.

```
if (message.content.split(" ")[0] == prefix + "sendchat") {
    //sendchat command
    message.delete();
    var commandSplit = message.content.split(" ");
    var commandSplitMSG = message.content.split(prefix + "sendchat ");
    var sendChatCommand = commandSplit[0];
    var sendChatMsg = commandSplitMSG;
    if (message.member.roles.find("id", adminRole)) {
      if (sendChatMsg == undefined) {
        message.reply("Please specify a command to send!");
      } else {
        message.reply("Sending the command: " + sendChatMsg);
        fs.appendFile("sendchat.txt", sendChatMsg, err => {
          if (err) throw err;
        });
      }
    }
```

It should just send the command without any of that and I need to be able to place a string in as the 2nd arg, so /sendchat "full string" the output should be "full string"

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at your code, you seem to be using `message.content.split(prefix + "sendchat ");`. This is fine, but when you use it, you are accessing it directly, but `.split()` returns an `array`. As an example,

```
"!sendchat hello world".split("!" + "sendchat ")
//["", "hello world"]
```

Looking at this, it seems you are passing this whole array to the file, and when you do `["", "hello world"].toString()`, you get `",hello world"` as the output. This explains the comma, because it is passing your array to a string when appending it to the file.

If you change

```
var sendChatMsg = commandSplitMSG;
//Given the example before, ["", "hello world"]
```

to

```
var sendChatMsg = commandSplitMSG[1];
//accessing [1] gets hello world
```

you should obtain the output you are looking for.